# Awk: find duplicates in 3rd field INCLUDING original

Tags: dictionary, awk, associative-array

I figured out the following code to find duplicate UIDs in a passwd file, but it doesn't include the first instance (the one that was later duplicated), I ultimately wanted to have a dictionary with `UID = [ USER1, USER2 ]` but I am not sure how to get it done in Awk.

What I have so far:

```
awk -F':' '$1 !~ /^#/ &&  _[$3]++ {print}' /etc/passwd
```

Explanation (as I understand it), if regex matches a line not beginning with comment '#', then increment an array based on the current line UID value which makes that line become a non-zero/True value thus printing it.

Comment: You can't tell the difference between a UID that will be duplicated and one that won't when you see it the first time not during scan at least. You'll need to save all the matching lines and print out at the end for this.

Comment: What is the most memory efficient way to do that using this type of Awk statement?

Comment: Best I can think of is to store every "first" line during processing and then loop at the `END` and print each "first" line with a count more than 1.

Comment: Don't use a variable named `_`. You can't REALLY think doing that makes your code more readable or better in any other possible way. Post sample input and expected output and if you want your final output to look like `UID = [ USER1, USER2 ]` then show THAT, not some unnecessary intermediate form like your current script would produce.

Comment: @EdMorton  If I hadn't supplied some "intermediate" version of a solution, someone else would be complaining that I hadn't shown any effort to solve this problem which seems to also be frowned upon in this community.  I cannot please everyone, unfortunately.

Comment: It's fine to show some intermediate form if you think it will be helpful, but don't ONLY show that - it's far more important to show what you want your final output to be. You can definitely please everyone by just stating the question clearly, showing what you have attempted, and showing sample input and expected output that we could test a possible solution against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you to do it. First we save in an array the data, and in the END{} block we print all repeated lines in the array (also you have a print in execution time). Hope it helps you

```
awk -F":" '
    $1 !~ /^#/ && (counter[$3]>0) {a++;print "REPEATED|UID:"$3"|"$0"|"LastReaded[$3]; repeateds["a"a]=$0; repeateds["b"a]=LastReaded[$3]}
    $1 !~ /^#/ { counter[$3]++; LastReaded[$3]=$0} 
    END {for (i in repeateds)
         {
            print i"|"repeateds[i]
         }
    }
' /etc/passwd  

REPEATED|UID:229|pepito:*:229:229:pepito:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false|_avbdeviced:*:229:-2:Ethernet AVB Device Daemon:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
a1|pepito:*:229:229:pepito:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
b1|_avbdeviced:*:229:-2:Ethernet AVB Device Daemon:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```